# Model.find is not a function mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mini casino game and have a mongoose model defined as following:

```
const jackpotSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    round_id: {
        type: String, 
        default: uniqid(), 
        required: true, 
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date, 
        required: true, 
        default: Date.now
    },

    closedAt: {
        type: Date,
    },

    startedAt: {
        type: Number, 
    }, 

    roundSecret: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
    }, 

    random_org_hash: {
        type: String,
    },

    random_org_obj: {
        type: String
    },

    roundSecretHash: {
        type: String, 
    },
    
    winningPercentage: {
        type: Number, 
        // required: true, 
        // first 5 characters of the secret hash, converted into decimal then divided by 10K 
    },
    publicHash: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        // SHA-256 roundSecret + winningPercentage
    },

    finalHash: {
        type: String, 
    },

    winningTicket: {
        type: Number, 
    },

    winningDepositIndex: {
        type: Number, 
    },

    deposits: [{
        uid: {
            type: String, 
            required: true,
        }, 

        user: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
        },

        nonce: {
            type: Number,
        },

        amount: {
            type: Number, 
            required: true, 
        }, 

        user_avatar: {
            type: String, 
        }, 

        ticketRangeMin: {
            type: Number, 
            required: true, 
        }, 

        ticketRangeMax: {
            type: Number, 
            required: true, 
        },

        referral: {type: String},
        timestamp: {type: Date}, 
        timestamp_readable: {type: String}
    }],

    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true, 
        default: 0, 
    },

    totalTickets: {
        type: Number, 
        default: 0, 
    }, 

    winner: {
        type: String, 
        default: "",
    },

    winner_avatar: {
        type: String,
    },

    active: {
        type: Boolean, 
        default: true, 
        required: true, 
    },

    open: {
        type: Boolean, 
        required: true,
        default: true,  
    },

    roundTime: {
        type: Number, 
        // default: potConfig.potLength, 
        default: 20000, 
    },

    success: {
        type: Boolean,
    },

    fee: {
        type: Number, 
        default: potConfig.potFee,
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Jackpot", jackpotSchema)
```

When running my app locally, I experience no errors.
However when running on a ubuntu production environment, I get the following error:
`Jackpot.find is not a function`

The stack trace says that the error is coming from db_utils.js
which looks like the following:

```
const Jackpot   = require("./models/Jackpot");
...
async retrieveStats () {
  var jackpots = await Jackpot.find().lean();
}
```

I have checked to see whether my module.exports was defined correctly, and it is. Not sure why this error is happening.

My local and production node versions match.
12.18.4

Comment: const mongoose = require("mongoose");

yea

Comment: Then check your file name `Jackpot` in line `require("./models/Jackpot")`

Comment: Looks to be correct.
https://prnt.sc/10y4foy

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to do

```
const jackpotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...})
```

instead of

```
 const jackpotSchema = mongoose.Schema({...})
```

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't seem to fix anything. How I was doing it before, worked on my local environment.

Comment: Are you facing issue in only Jackpot model or all models? Coinflip etc is working? If yes could you paste an example of one of those files? @Lorza

Sorry I can't comment on your question as I am a new user hence commenting here.

Comment: I'm only facing this problem with jackpot that's right.
I'll paste the entirety of both files.

Comment: jackpot: https://pastebin.com/gUeV66td
db_utils: https://pastebin.com/0Ea6U72A

Comment: retrieveBankrollStats is the function in question that is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for pasting both the files in question, but I wish to see "CoinFlip" or any other model that works, I believe a hint to solve Jackpot is in there.